# How to check uploaded file is password protected or not?

Tags: java, api, passwords

We have a requirement to check whether an uploaded file is password protected or not. File type can be any common types like doc, xml, xls, pdf etc...

Also I can't use third party API's since that is not permitted by our security policy. So we are basically allowed to use core security Java API's only.

Thanks in Advance...
Pradeep

Comment: Hello! Did you try *anything* before posting? Can you show us any code?

Comment: And the question is...? No there is no such API in core Java. Good news: you have a lot of work for the next year or so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operating system specific (as far as I know the common operating systems) property of a file that tells you it is password-protected.

The process for the file formats (and most others as well) is this:

- The appropriate program tries to open the file (Word, Adobe Reader, etc.)
- The program notices while parsing the file, that the file-format-specific flag for password protection is set.
- The program shows you a password prompt and then attempts to decrypt it

This means, your options are:

1. Consult the documentation of all the file formats you want your users to be able to upload, and implement parsing for each file format to find out if a password has been set yourself
2. Use third-party libraries for the file formats you want to support and let them do the parsing and password-protection checking.

Option 1 obviously is a huge development cost. Option 2 is disallowed by your policies.

My advice would be: either drop the feature or rethink the requirement for 'no 3rd party libraries'. The second would make much more sense, since Java has a huge amount of 3rd party libraries available that will save you hours/days/months of developing features yourself.

Comment: Thanks Timo for your reply. Can you mention few 3rd party API's we can use for this case...Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you there. I've been using Apache POI for Office files, but I've never used anything password-related.

Comment: you can use apache poi for this purpose. check below link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407725/get-the-excel-workbook-password-using-apache-poi